# How to select a HTML tag with a specific class?

Tags: html, css

I need to apply some css styles to a tag with a specific class, for example I need to select `article` tag with `news` class.

```
<article class="news" >
  <div>some stuff</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way with CSS:

```css
article.news{
  /* add styles below */
}
```

You can do it this way with JavaScript:

```js
let articleNews = document.querySelector("article.news");
// for example
articleNews.style.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Select and style all elements with class="news":

syntax:

```
.class {
  css declarations;
}
```

for example

```
.news{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```